# How do I create a user-input column in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to SQL Server Reporting Services and report designing; can anyone help me in this?

I have two questions:

1. How can I create a column for users to input data?  After that, I need to perform some operations on the data entered by the user, which I need to display in another column.
2. How can I round a decimal to the nearest integer?  For example, 6.03 to 6 and 6.52 to 7.

Answer (score 3):

> 1) How to create a column to input user data and after that I need to
>   perform some operations on data enter by the user which i need to
>   display in another column

SSRS is not creating an application, just a report. It is not advisable to use SSRS to collect user input. A limited amount can be done using parameters but this is on a per report basis not per row as I think you're implying in the question. For example you could have a parameter to multiple values by a common factor and then display that result.

> 2)how to make round a decimal to nearest integer ex 6.03 to 6 and 6.52
>   to 7

Create an expression with the Round() function.

```
=Round(6.03)
```

this returns 6. Round also accepts a second value for number of decimal places. But instead of literal value, your fieldname would be in the parentheses:

```
=Round(myFieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SSRS as a front end of an "application" is not advisable.  That said, sometimes you only have a hammer and those screws are going in by themself.

If you are looking for an in-line edit, you are out of luck with anything vanilla (and something like injecting jQuery is very strawberry).  You can, however, create a link to a secondary report that is solely used for collecting the input (through parameters), then updating the source data for your report.  After the user has entered the data, they need to click 'View Report', which isn't a great experience, but doable.  The report results would be a confirmation of the change you just made

Going back to the original report can be tricky. If it lacks any parameters, you can provide a link back to it.  If it has parameters, however, you need to build the URL to get back to the original report (include parameters) and include that as an argument to your "line edit" form.  Your "line edit" form then will use that for providing a link back.  You will have to use `http://ssrs/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx`, versus `http://ssrs/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx` which means that all bread crumbs go away.

Side note: if you are trying to edit, and start with an initial value (e.g. the value you want to change as the starting point), add a 'confirm' dropdown with 1 value not defaulted.  This will require the user to change it, but will prevent the form from auto "viewing" which will call your update SQL.

Comment: And yes, I know this is an old question, but I am actively having to do this on a 2008 instance as now, so I know it is still relevant for some.